# Which is the correct form of a verb with two subjects?

Tags: grammatical-number, technical

In order to replace timing belt two hoses and holding bracket **need** to be removed.

Or:

In order to replace timing belt two hoses and holding bracket needs to be removed.

Comment: Hello, Tom. Usually, if  2 or more items in a subject are in the same class, or are related for some reason, it would be a a singular verb i.e. "needs". These sound unrelated, so I would go with "need". Also...put a comma between "belt" and "two" to improve reading.

Comment: You also need some articles: “In order to replace ***the*** timing belt, two hoses and ***a*** holding bracket need to be removed.”

Comment: @Jim Yeah..I was thinking the same, but as this is technical writing, I thought those could be overlooked. In this case, there is only _one_ timing belt, and _one_ bracket. Sorry I am coming off all Mr. mechanic.

Comment: You need ***(a / the)*** *timing belt, two hoses, and* ***(a / the)*** *bracket*. Or, possibly, *timing* ***belts*** and *holding* ***brackets***.

Answer (score 2):

The third person plural of need is 'need'. 'Needs' is used for third person singular.

"two hoses and a holding bracket" is plural, so you would use 'need'.

Comment: Erm...you VTCed, but provided an answer? How is that any different to answering in comment?

Comment: I expected it to be migrated to ELL, in which case the answer would go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Tom, I believe it would be "need" because when it is plural(2 or more objects) you would use need, but if your subject was singular you would use "needs". For you I would add some articles so it would flow better  ex. the, a, an (these are the only articles) An would be used if the next word started with a vowel. Hope this helps